# css variables not "calculating" color?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to assign block-level css variables with values taken from sass. But the following line `color: hsl(3, 75%, var(--main-color-l));` will not output any result. I am using a static site generator with scss pipes. Any reasons why?

```css
.reveal .palette1 {
    --main-color-h: $red-h;
    --main-color-s: $red-s;
    --main-color-l: $red-l;
    --main-color-o: $red-o;
    h2 {
        /**/color: hsl(3, 75%, var(--main-color-l));/**/
    }
    h4 {
        color: hsla($red-h, $red-s, $red-l * 1.3, $red-o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```scss
$red-h: 235;
$red-s: 100%;
$red-l: 50%;
$red-o: .5;

:root {
--main-color-h: #{$red-h};
--main-color-s: #{$red-s};
--main-color-l: #{$red-l};
--main-color-o: #{$red-o};
}

h2 {
    color: hsl(3, 75%, var(--main-color-l));
}

h4 {
    color: hsla($red-h, $red-s, $red-l, $red-o);
}
```

Comment: this isn't working. My file is in .scss. It seems that is the issue, it'd have to be .css? I'd prefer to stick with scss though so I will find workarounds.

Comment: I completely overhauled my solution. Using SassMeister (https://www.sassmeister.com/), this is working. Yes, you should keep the .scss file extension when using sass variables.